# Makefile - Connexion Refused when creating database

Tags: docker, symfony, makefile

I have a project with 4 container : one for react, one for php-apache, one for the mySQL database and one for PHPMyAdmin.

I use symfony and i try to make the installation easy with a Makefile.

My problem is that when I run my makefile command ( make init ) everything run fine a part the database création. I encounter a « SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused » error.

But if I run the command manually, the database is created and there is no error.

I tried to wait with a while loop and sleep to be sure that the MySQL container ports are open, but it doesnt work.

Any idea to solve that ?

Here are my Makefile and my Docker-compose :

Makefile :

```
# Variables
DOCKER_COMPOSE = docker-compose
EXEC =  docker exec -it www_resrel bash
NPM = $(EXEC) npm
SYMFONY_CONSOLE = bin/console

# Colors
GREEN = /bin/echo -e "\x1b[32m\#\# $1\x1b[0m"
RED = /bin/echo -e "\x1b[31m\#\# $1\x1b[0m"

## ——  App ——
init: ## Init the project
    $(MAKE) docker-start
    cp .env.example .env
    $(MAKE) composer-install
    $(MAKE) database-init
    $(MAKE) jwt-keys

    @$(call GREEN,"Symfony is available at: http://127.0.0.1:8000/.")
    @$(call GREEN,"React is available at: http://127.0.0.1:3000/.")
    @$(call GREEN,"PhpMyAdmin is available at: http://127.0.0.1:8080/.")

cache-clear: ## Clear cache
    $(EXEC) -c "bin/console cache:clear; exit"

## ——  Docker ——

docker-start: 
    $(DOCKER_COMPOSE) up -d

jwt-keys: ## Generate JWT keys
    $(EXEC) -c "bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair"

## ——  Composer ——
composer-install: ## Install dependencies
    composer install

composer-update: ## Update dependencies
    $(COMPOSER) update

## ——  Database ——
database-init: ## Init database
    $(MAKE) database-drop
    $(MAKE) database-create
    $(MAKE) database-migrate
    $(MAKE) database-fixtures-load
    $(MAKE) database-drop-test
    $(MAKE) database-create-test
    $(MAKE) database-migrate-test
    $(MAKE) database-fixtures-load-test
    @$(call GREEN,"Database and test database have been initialized.")

database-drop: ## Drop database
    $(EXEC) -c "bin/console d:d:d --force --if-exists"

database-create: ## Create database
    $(EXEC) -c "bin/console d:d:c --if-not-exists"

database-migration: ## Make migration
    $(EXEC) -c "bin/console make:migration"

migration: ## Alias : database-migration
    $(EXEC) -c "bin/console database-migration"

database-migrate: ## Migrate migrations
    $(EXEC) -c "bin/console d:m:m --no-interaction"

migrate: ## Alias : database-migrate
    $(EXEC) -c "bin/console database-migrate"

database-fixtures-load: ## Load fixtures
    $(EXEC) -c "bin/console d:f:l --no-interaction"



fixtures: ## Alias : database-fixtures-load
    $(EXEC) -c "bin/console database-fixtures-load"

## ——  Database test ——

database-drop-test: ## Drop database
    $(EXEC) -c "bin/console d:d:d --env=test --force --if-exists"

database-create-test: ## Create test database
    $(EXEC) -c "bin/console d:d:c --env=test --if-not-exists"

database-migrate-test: ## Migrate migrations
    $(EXEC) -c "bin/console d:m:m --env=test --no-interaction"

database-fixtures-load-test: ## Load test fixtures
    $(EXEC) -c "bin/console d:f:l --env=test --no-interaction"


## —— ️  Others ——
help: ## List of commands
    @grep -E '(^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+:.*?##.*$$)|(^##)' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "}{printf "\033[32m%-30s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}' | sed -e 's/\[32m##/[33m/'
```

Docker-compose :

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: db_resrel
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    networks:
      - dev

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin_resrel
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
    networks:
      - dev

  www:
    build: docker
    container_name: www_resrel
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./api:/var/www
    networks:
      - dev
  
  app:
    build: app
    container_name: app_resrel
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules

networks:
  dev:

volumes:
  db-data:
```

Comment: Please include `docker-compose.yml` in your question.

Comment: How have you configured the database connection in your application?  Why are you using the `docker exec` debugging command so extensively; can you run migrations as part of your image's entrypoint wrapper script, perhaps, without needing a manual step?  Why are you running `compose` on the host rather than in the Dockerfile?

Comment: What does "But if I run the command manually, the database is created and there is no error." mean exactly?